# python pdfpage.extract_words throws error

Tags: python-3.x, text-extraction, python-pdfkit

I have this code in my project to get all the words from pdf.

words = pdfPage.extract_words(0.5,0.5)

which throws the below error:

Cannot convert  to Decimal.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: After tried for several hours, I just downgrade the version of pdfminer and it works fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to downgrade the Pdf-minder version. Since i had this same issue resolving by downgrading.